# Nautilus title bar menus have disappeared in 16.10

Tags: nautilus, menu-bar

I have two systems that I did an in place upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 and both are missing the menu options in Nautilus.  I get the file menu option but the option under it are incomplete as in this screen shot.

**MissingMenusUbuntu16.10**[image]

Comment: hi is the answer below sufficient?, then pls mark the question as solved else comment on the answer pls

Answer (score 1):

This was done intentionally, as `nautilus` is part of the Gnome project, which decided to flush out the menu-bars and replace them with a button in the window. [image: New Gnome Menus]